# Add custom plugin to just one page in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins

I am really new to wordpress and want to add a plugin I created to a page I have added in wordpress.

The page I have added is called "booking" and all it contains at the moment is the header and footer.

The plugin is a folder which will return a booking process.

In the php file I have the following:

````
function sc_booking_process() {
    if ( is_page( 'booking' ) ) {
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_regForm_validation' );
    }


    return '<div id="choices">
    <h2>Ticket Purchase</h2>
    <h3> Select Ticket Types</h3>
   <form id="form1" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return calcTotal(this)">
      <table id="tickets" style="float:left">
        <thead>
            <th>Ticket Type</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th class="Quantity">Quantity</th>
        </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Adult <span class = "small-text">18 +</span></td>
            <td>&#128;10.00</td>
            <td class="Quantity">
                <select name="select1">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="10">1</option>
                <option value="20">2</option>
                 <option value="30">3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Child <span class = "small-text">12 years and under</span></td>
            <td>&#128;6.00</td>
            <td class="Quantity">
                <select name="select1">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="6">1</option>
                    <option value="12">2</option>
                    <option value="18">3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Teen <span class = "small-text">13 - 17 years</span></td>
            <td>&#128;7.00</td>
            <td class="Quantity">
                <select name="select1">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="7">1</option>
                    <option value="14">2</option>
                    <option value="21">3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <td><input name="" type="submit" value="Proceed" onclick = "hide()"/></td>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
}```
I assume the add_action is done wrong as I'm not sure what function I should have instead of wp_enqueue_scripts.

Any advice on how to fix this would be really appreciated. Thanks!
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return/render the html using a shortcode function and then use that either in the booking page template or in the WordPress content editor window for the booking page.

Checkout the WP shortcode API:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

***Edit:*** 
I just saw the end of the code sample you posted. It looks like some of your question was still wrapped in the code styling.  Anyway, are you looking to just enqueue the script only on the booking page? If so, the conditional check you have should work.

If you're looking to render the html, I still suggest a shortcode. Here's snippet you could use that would call your function `sc_booking_process` using a shortcode.

add

```
add_shortcode('name_of_shortcode', 'sc_booking_process');
```

to your function file and then call the function using either

```
[name_of_shortCode][/name_of_shortCode]
```

in a WYIWYG editor or

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[name_of_shortcode]'); ?>
```

in your theme files.